# SSJS SimpleOperator contains string or null

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to search for records which contain either a value or is empty using SSJS using the following line but it doesn't yield any results.

```
var Filter = {Property:"status",SimpleOperator:"IN",Value:["pending", null]};
```

Can anyone explain how I could do this correctly?

Comment: I believe (depending on the function that is using that filter) you might need to do a complex filter with status equals X OR status isnull (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/simpleoperators.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to make this into a complex filter as the IN will not recognize the null as a value to match on and will never return a value of true.

SFMC is (to simplify) utilizing SQL for these filters and SQL utilizes [Three-value logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), which essentially means that you cannot use operators like `=, !=, >, <,etc.` to match on Null as Null compared to anything will return Null which will fail the filter (requires a returned value of true to pass).

So you will need to utilize the [built in Null operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/simpleoperators.htm) in order to grab those associated. See below for example of utilizing this logic.

```
var Filter = {
    LeftOperand: {
        Property: "status",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "pending"
    },
    LogicalOperator: "OR",
    RightOperand: {
        Property: "status",
        SimpleOperator: "isNull"
    }
}
```